# Problema no armazenamento de dados no vetor

Tags: c, loop

Estou aprendendo a programar e estou com dificuldades de lógica em achar o erro desse programa.

O vetor de notas está armazenando as 6 notas (2 de cada aluno), mas só põe no vetor as ultimas duas. O problema deve estar no loop/for, mas não consigo identificar.

```
/* Criar um programa capaz de ler duas notas de cada
um dos 3 alunos de uma turma, calculando a média
geral da primeira e da segunda prova. OBS: use função.
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define qtdAlunos 3
#define qtdNotas 2

float media(float notas[20]){
    float soma, media;
    for(int i=0; i<qtdAlunos; i++){
        for(int n=0; n<qtdNotas; n++){
            soma+=notas[n];
        }
    }
    media=soma/(qtdNotas*qtdAlunos);
    
    return media;
}

int main(){
    float notas[20];
    
    for(int i=0; i<qtdAlunos; i++){
        for(int n=0; n<qtdNotas; n++){
            printf("Digite a nota %d do aluno %d: ", n+1, i+1);
            scanf("%f", &notas[n]);
            
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
   
    printf("A media das notas é: %f", media(notas));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A questão é que você está usando apenas um vetor (unidimentsional) para armazenar as notas. Então o que acontece é que você está tentando armazenar 6 notas nas mesmas duas posições do vetor "notas[]", então o programa acaba sobrescrevendo e ficando só as últimas.

Você vai ter que usar uma matriz, que um vetor bidimensional, basicamente, e ao colocar essa matriz dentro do for, implementar que vai sendo acessada a linha de cada aluno, e a coluna de cada nota (ou vice-versa). Assim:

(considerando até 3 alunos, e até 20 notas por aluno)

```
int main() {

float notas[3][20];

for(int i=0; i<qtdAlunos; i++){
    for(int n=0; n<qtdNotas; n++){
        printf("Digite a nota %d do aluno %d: ", n+1, i+1);
        scanf("%f", &notas[i][n]);

}
```

Se não tiver visto esse conteúdo, recomendo estudar o assunto. Vídeo aulas no youtube sobre matriz na linguagem c devem te ajudar. Espero ter ajudado!